# Possible nullpointer exception android

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an app in android that uses gestures to represent letters. I have an element of a string array displayed in the text area so the user knows what letter to draw. 
I declare this globally:

```
    Resources res = getResources();
String [] letters = res.getStringArray(R.array.LetterToBeDrawn)
```

Then I have this in my oncreate:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
tv.setText("Draw the letter: "+letters[i]);
```

And in my gesturePerformed method I've got this comparison:

```
if (predictions.size() > 0)
{
    Prediction prediction = predictions.get(0);
    if (prediction.score > 1.0 && prediction.name.equals(letters[i]))
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, prediction.name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

When I go to launch this on my emulator I get a lot of errors in the LogCat, and they seem to be caused by a NullPointerException. But I can't see how that could be as the array at the moment only contains three items and the index int i is set to 1.

EDIT: Here's the LogCat, meant to post it earlier:

```
04-25 15:37:31.266: D/AndroidRuntime(1889): Shutting down VM
04-25 15:37:31.266: W/dalvikvm(1889): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a4eb90)
04-25 15:37:31.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1889): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-25 15:37:31.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1889): Process: com.gmail.Sheridjohn.letterchecker, PID: 1889
04-25 15:37:31.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1889): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.gmail.Sheridjohn.letterchecker/com.gmail.Sheridjohn.letterchecker.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-25 15:37:31.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1889):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2102)
04-25 15:37:31.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1889):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
04-25 15:37:31.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1889):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-25 15:37:31.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1889):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
04-25 15:37:31.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1889):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-25 15:37:31.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1889):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-25 15:37:31.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1889):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
04-25 15:37:31.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1889):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-25 15:37:31.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1889):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-25 15:37:31.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1889):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
04-25 15:37:31.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1889):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
04-25 15:37:31.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1889):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-25 15:37:31.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1889): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-25 15:37:31.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1889):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:89)
04-25 15:37:31.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1889):     at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:78)
04-25 15:37:31.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1889):     at com.gmail.Sheridjohn.letterchecker.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:21)
04-25 15:37:31.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1889):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
04-25 15:37:31.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1889):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
04-25 15:37:31.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1889):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
04-25 15:37:31.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1889):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2093)
04-25 15:37:31.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1889):     ... 11 more
```

Here's my XML:

```
<android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/gestures"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        />

</android.gesture.GestureOverlayView>
```

Comment: Could you post your Logcat please?

Comment: When speaking of errors, please, post them along with all the code.

Comment: Are you getting a NPE at tv.setText()?

Comment: `prediction` is null?  btw, please learn to use the debugger.  These problems are the simplest of all bugs to find.  Put a breakpoint on the first line of the method, run your app, step through until you see the problem.  Job done.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-25 15:37:31.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1889):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:89)
04-25 15:37:31.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1889):     at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:78)
04-25 15:37:31.366: E/AndroidRuntime(1889):     at com.gmail.Sheridjohn.letterchecker.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:21)` - what is line 21?

Comment: You need to post more of the class you are having this issue in, 10 lines of code without any context is not enough to debug properly. Also please post your xml so we can determine whether or not you have declared that textview properly

Comment: So dcahrms spotted it, `String [] letters = res.getStringArray(R.array.LetterToBeDrawn)` is line 21?

Comment: Line 21 is Resources res = getResources();
If i move it into my onCreate() then my program doesn't recognise letters[i] in my gesturePerformed method

Comment: Nope, leave the declaration where it is, move the initialiser to onCreate().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getResources()` is null when you declare it globally. Move the initializations of both `res` and `letters` to your `onCreate()` method and keep the declarations where you currently have them.

Comment: Good spot.  I missed that.